# Unable to run Appium test on Android 7.0 / 7.1

Tags: android, selenium, automation, appium, appium-android

My pc is ready for Appium, its working fine for Android 6.0, but while trying to run on Android 7.0 / 7.1 its not working. While trying to run test script(which already worked fine on 6.0) on android(7.0) device, it just tying to open `AppiumSettings` app and at this moment going to fail.
    PC OS: Windows 10
    Appium version: 1.7.1
    Npm version: 3.10.3

I'm using below dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Server error log:**

```
[debug] [ADB] Restarting adb
[debug] [ADB] Killing adb server on port 5037
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[debug] [AndroidDriver] Called deleteSession but bootstrap wasn't active
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not find a connected Android device.
    at ADB.getDevices$ (../../../lib/tools/system-calls.js:187:13)
    at tryCatch (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
    at invoke (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
    at enqueueResult (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:185:17)
    at Promise.exports.(anonymous function).target.(anonymous function).function.target.(anonymous function).F (AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\core-js\library\modules\$.export.js:30:36)
    at AsyncIterator.enqueue (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:184:12)
    at AsyncIterator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
    at Object.runtime.async (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:209:12)
    at getDevices (../../../lib/tools/system-calls.js:190:18)
    at ADB.getDevices$ (../../../lib/tools/system-calls.js:204:20)
    at tryCatch (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\node_modules\babel-runtime\regenerator\runtime.js:136:37)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 29803 ms - 179
```

Comment: What does not working mean?

Comment: While trying to run test script(which already worked fine on 6.0) on android(7.0) device, it just tying to open `AppiumSettings` app and at this moment going to fail.

Comment: Is the Android 7 device an emulator? Or a physical device? If it is a physical device, you should enable development options. Also, make sure `adb devices` from the command line outputs a list of connected devices.

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you, my problem already solved.